# Trying to create a React Navigation Drawer with custom content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a React Navigation drawer with custom content (I want to put profile information, probably not any links). I am having a ton of trouble doing so.

Here's my basic stack/drawer:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNav() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
      <Text>Test Content</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{
          headerShown: false
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Leagues" component={Leagues} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
          headerRight: (navigation) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(navigation) => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>
              <EvilIcons name="navicon" size={50} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            null
          ),
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="CommForm" component={CommForm} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

All I want, literally all I want, is a sidebar that I can toggle by pressing the `<TouchableOpacity>` button above with custom content inside of it.

I am able to do this with React Native Side Menu, but it seems like if I am using React Navigation, I should learn how to do it with this library, however it seems very difficult to do what I am trying to do.

How do I create a sidebar with custom content with React Navigation? I primarily want to use Stack navigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem label="..." />
      // ...
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

function StackNavigator({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button title="press" onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      // Your other screens... 
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function DrawerNavigator({navigation, route}) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

So you can set the drawer navigation to be your main navigator and your stack navigation to be a screen of the drawer navigation. This way you can toggle the drawer without first navigating to it.

For creating custom drawer content you can pass a component to the `drawerContent` on the drawer navigator.

If you're going to use `DrawerContentScrollView` and/or `DrawerItem` like I've done in this example, be sure to import it from `'@react-navigation/drawer';` .

Look at the documentation for more information https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent.

Comment: Perfect! This works great. Is there any negative to having the Drawer being the main navigator? I'm not totally sure why these three types of navigators are separated. I'm used to React Router and React Navigation works quite differently

Comment: The main thing with react navigation is that we can't have navigators next to each other inside a navigation container. So if you want multiple different kinds of navigators it means one navigator needs to be a screen of another. So nesting different navigators is normal. It's totally fine to have a drawer (or any other type) as a main navigator. It's more a question of what do you want to be accessible on what screens.